# How to download silently with javascript

Tags: javascript, download, file-transfer

I am new in javascript and I have some trouble to complete an activity...

I need working, in the client side, with the information uploaded in a "special" server like this:

http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/71051/11558879/ExampleData.json/0a635cdd-ccdd-4a1c-8c88-b53bea431458

I want load it in main memory, without the browser show the explicit download.

I try to use some solutions, but really I have no idea how to proceed to achieve it.

... Beforehand thank you very much

(I am not a native english speaker, I apologize if I do not write well)

**[Solved]**

I decided, for the moment, use the Whatever Origin services, that returns me something I can read with $.getJSON "Without download" the file.

Resulted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + "http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/71051/11558879/ExampleData.json/0a635cdd-ccdd-4a1c-8c88-b53bea431458" + '&callback=?', function(data){
        alert(data.contents);
      });
 </script>
```

***Thank you for yours responses, really you gave me lights in order to solve it***

Comment: I think you are looking for Ajax. Or JSON-P. Two techniques that allow Javascript to request a file from somewhere without leaving the current page and without it being obvious to the user - at least until, presumably, you use the data in the file to update the page somehow.

Comment: $.getJSON works for me by the moment, but I continue the investigation about the best road to solved it, thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding silent part**

Your browser is always aware of the network requests which are made from JS. Therefore, the user can always see all the requests and responses by opening developer tools.

---

**Now coming to loading a remote json to the memory in the client**

Since you mentioned you are relatively a newbie in JS, I am going to cover the very basic, so please bear with me if you already know it

You need to make an ajax call using an XMLHttpRequest as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

---

However, most people use some library like jQuery while working to abstract checking state of the request and other trivial tasks. This results in making an ajax call as simple as calling a method and providing a callback method to process the response.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
  dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
  console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

You may find the example at below link.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

P.S.: **Due the less reputation points, I can neither post any supporting images nor more than two links.**

Comment: Oh thanks,I could notice that I received "No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin ... Origin null is therefore not allowed access." (why? I don't know, the link works perfectly)

I will read more about the item, by the moment I solved for other side.