# Javascript download an on-the-fly generated BLOB file into specific folder

Tags: javascript, download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I'm trying to write a Firefox Webextension.
I want to save title, url and a personal comment of a webpage into a file, `myfile.txt`

Here it is what I came to:

[image]

I don't want my Downloads folder to become rapidly full, so I would like to download them in a folder contained inside my Downloads folder, let's call it `VNW`.
FIY I'm saying 'download' but it is a dummy download: I construct the file on the fly and I managed to save like this: You don't require Internet connection.

I wrote this code:

```
var textToSave = "<TITLE>" + titolo + "</TITLE>"  + "<COMMENT>" + comment + "</COMMENT>" + "<LINK>" + indirizzo + "</LINK>" + "\n"; 
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('SAVE');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
hiddenElement.download = 'VNW/myfile.txt';
```

Bad things it saves the file in my `Downloads` folder instead of `Downloads/VNW` as I'm expecting, and it saves the file as `VNW_myfile.txt`

Why?

Question in the question: When I open in an editor `myfile.txt` I'm getting,for example:

```
<TITLE>How to download silently with javascript - Stack Overflow</TITLE><COMMENT>My comment</COMMENT><LINK>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781938/how-to-download-silently-with-javascript
```

Where the final `</LINK>` tag is trimmed...and I can't imagine why...:(
Is there a way I can download the file silently, without prompting the user every time like this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT 1:**

Using Daniel Herr comment I'm writing (I am a Javascript beginner)

```
var comment = document.getElementById('COMMENT').value;
var titolo=document.getElementById('TITLE_TAB').value;
var indirizzo=document.getElementById('URL_TAB').value;
var textToSave = "<TITLE>" + titolo + "</TITLE>"  + "<COMMENT>" + comment + "</COMMENT>" + "<LINK>" + indirizzo + "</LINK>" + "\n"; 
var downloading;
var txt_saving =  'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
downloading = browser.downloads.download(url : txt_saving,filename : 'VNW.txt');
```

But it doesn't work...
Thanks again

**EDIT 2**
Thanks again to Daniel, I'm approaching the solution, but I'm not still there.

Thanks to your code, it starts the download but it says it failed like in the image [image]

I checked my manifest, downloads is correctly there.

Here it is,

```
{
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "TENTATIVO",
    "default_popup": "save_url.html"
  },
  "description": "TENTATIVO",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TENTATIVO",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "save.png",
    "default_title": "TENTATIVO"
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Adding also all the code for reference.

save_url.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css"/>
  </head>

<body onload="save_url.js">
  <div style="margin-left:5%" id="BODY">
  <form>
  <br>
  <strong>TITOLO:</strong>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="" id="TITLE_TAB" style="width:90%;"></input>
  <br>
  <strong>URL:</strong>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="" id="URL_TAB" style="width:90%;"></input>
  <br>
  <strong>DESCRIZIONE:</strong>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="5" placeholder="Descrizione.." style="width:90%;" id="COMMENT"></textarea>
  <br>
  <center>
  <a href="" id="SAVE" style="width:90%;" value = "" >SALVA</a>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
  </form>
  </div>
  <script src="save_url.js"></script>
  <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

save_url.js

```
browser.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    var title = tabs[0].title;

    var x = document.getElementById("URL_TAB");
    x.value = url;
    var y = document.getElementById("TITLE_TAB");
    y.value = title;
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("SAVE").addEventListener("click", salva);
});

function salva()
{
    var comment = document.getElementById('COMMENT').value;
    var titolo=document.getElementById('TITLE_TAB').value;
    var indirizzo=document.getElementById('URL_TAB').value;
    var textToSave = "<TITLE>" + titolo + "</TITLE>"  + "<COMMENT>" + comment + "</COMMENT>" + "<LINK>" + indirizzo + "</LINK>" + "\n"; 

    browser.downloads.download({
                                url: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ textToSave ])),
                                filename: "test/test.txt",
                                })
}
```

**EDIT 3** Solved.

I actually wrote a blog post (my very first!), thanks for all the help.

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks. Think I came to that link but abandoned since I'm a beginner. However, can you please suggest how can I make the download? What do I pass to `url` in that function? It isn't a url, instead a mechanism I use to save the content of a JS variable to a file.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the downloads api and add the "downloads" permission to the manifest.

```
browser.downloads.download({
 url: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ textToSave ])),
 filename: "test/test.txt",
 saveAs: false,
})
```

If the `filename` is a path, any parent folders will be created if needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download

Subfolders require Firefox 51+
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1280044

Comment: Sorry I answered your comment, I only see now your answer. I'm quite there, thanks for your help, but now it says "Failed"..(I updated my question).In the end I'm paying you a beer!

Comment: I have that message also on 50. Are you on Firefox 51?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit with Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: problem could be subfolder, but the main problem is that if I erase `test/test.txt` and I just write `test.txt` it is failing again! This happen both with the code you are suggesting and with the code I found on the link you kindly provided.

Comment: Also found this one https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271345   They say fixed but I guess not,it doesn't work... Is it just me?! :(  or because I'm a beginner and I didn't understand.

Comment: I'm wondering: is there a workaround around `browser.downloads.download`?

Comment: It is also failing on Firefox Nightly 53.0.1

Comment: You should comment on that bug that it is not fixed.

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually I made it work, and wrote a blog post. Thanks indeed for your kind help again! https://csprio30.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/a-firefox-webextension-to-save-interesting-stuff-found-online/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a leading / or \ in front your file-destination (/VNW/..) or use a full file-destination (..\downloads\VNW\myfile.txt) Are you running this on your own server? Maybe you may need to explore your file system structure a little more??? You might need to capture the users chosen filepath from the browser?

Comment: Yes, tried..nothing changed.. the '/' is always replaced with '_' when saving..I forgot to mention I'm running Ubuntu. I'm running it on my browser, locally, on my laptop. "..users chosen filepath.." nah!! it has to be fixed! users don't have to be bothered like that!

Comment: Sounds silly but have you checked your permissions for the directory?

Comment: From you first lines 'Bad things it saves the file in my Downloads folder instead of Downloads/VNW as I'm expecting, and it saves the file as VNW_myfile.txt' it seems that this is an error linked to 'code' hiddenElement.download = 'VNW/myfile.txt'; 'code' ... maybe where the / is being replaced by an _ ??? That would explain it not going into the subdirectory AND the filename being different.