# Initiate download to a subdirectory of Downloads folder

Tags: javascript, html, browser, download

Despite specificying a path, clicking the following initiates a download into the top level of the Downloads folder.

`<a download="subDir/test.png"> linktext </a>`

**Is there a way to specify a directory *within* Downloads?**

This is possible in a browser extension (see answer of [Javascript download an on-the-fly generated BLOB file into specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169569/javascript-download-an-on-the-fly-generated-blob-file-into-specific-folder)), but maybe not directly in HTML?

(Note: I am not trying to access the filesystem outside of Downloads, which I realize is a security concern.)

Comment: For security it is not possible to know the path to the download directory. Probably neither any subdirectory. Your idea would be great to implement in browsers, because it is not possible to read or overwrite files even if a subfolder is known by a hacker. I hate when security kills productivity! It is counterproductive to have an all in one mess download folder without structure.